# Got Key Error on Django Serializer when combining 2 models

Tags: django

Good day SO. I want to combine two models in one django serializer.
I just want to first get them inside one serializer and I can do the rest. Based on other SO question, I need to first declare a serializer and add it to my 2nd serializer. But it is giving me an error. I thought I just need to use the word major and declare it to my minor fields.

```
class PrefectureMajorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    text = serializers.CharField(source='prefecture_name')

    class Meta:
        model = PrefectureMajor
        fields = ["id", "text"]

class PrefectureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    text = serializers.CharField(source='prefecture_name')
    major = PrefectureMajorSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = PrefectureMinor
        fields = ['id', 'text', 'prefecture_major_id', 'major']
```

Models:

```
class PrefectureMajor(models.Model):
    prefecture_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', null=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.prefecture_name

class PrefectureMinor(models.Model):
    prefecture_major = models.ForeignKey("PrefectureMajor", related_name="PrefectureMinor.prefecture_name +", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    prefecture_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', null=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.prefecture_name
```

Traceback Error Message:

```
C:\Users\SOMEPATH\.virtualenvs\DjangoProjects-k8989gUR\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py, line 457, in get_attribute
            return get_attribute(instance, self.source_attrs) …
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
instance    
{'id': 1, 'is_active': True, 'prefecture_major_id': 2, 'prefecture_name': '北海道'}
msg 
('Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `major` on serializer '
 '`PrefectureSerializer`.\n'
 'The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute '
 'or key on the `dict` instance.\n'
 "Original exception text was: 'perfecture_major'.")
self    
PrefectureMajorSerializer(source='perfecture_major'):
    id = IntegerField()
    text = CharField(source='prefecture_name')
C:\Users\SOMEPATH\.virtualenvs\DjangoProjects-k8989gUR\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py, line 95, in get_attribute
                instance = instance[attr] …
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
attr    
'perfecture_major'
attrs   
['perfecture_major']
instance    
{'id': 1, 'is_active': True, 'prefecture_major_id': 2, 'prefecture_name': '北海道'}
```

View:

```
def get_all_prefectures(request):
    prefecture_list = PrefectureMinor.objects.filter(is_active=True).order_by("id").values()
    prefecture_serializer = PrefectureSerializer(prefecture_list, many=True)
    data = prefecture_serializer.data
    
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

Comment: Can you add the traceback for the error to your question?

Comment: Please share the relevant models.

Comment: Are you passing a dictionary to the serializer rather then a PrefectureMinor instance? Please post the code where you are using the serializer and the full traceback not just the error message

Comment: @rodjames: can you share the view you are using. Using `.values(..)` or `.values_list()` is not a good idea, since then one can no longer follow `ForeignKey`s.

Comment: I am actually just loading them as ajax

Answer (score 0):

The `ForeignKey` is `prefecture_major`, so you should use that as `source=…` for your serializer:

```
class PrefectureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    text = serializers.CharField(source='prefecture_name')
    major = PrefectureMajorSerializer(source='perfecture_major')

    class Meta:
        model = PrefectureMinor
        fields = ['id', 'text']
```

You should also *not* use [**`.values(…)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) since then you "erode" the model layer, and you thus can no longer follow the links to the related object.

Your view thus should look like:

```
def get_all_prefectures(request):
    prefecture_list = PrefectureMinor.objects.filter(
        is_active=True
    ).select_related('perfecture_major').order_by('id')
    prefecture_serializer = PrefectureSerializer(
        prefecture_list, many=True
    )
    data = prefecture_serializer.data
    
    return JsonResponse({'data': data})
```

The [**`.select_related(…)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) is not necessary, but will boost efficiency, since now we load both the `PerfectureMinor`, and its related `PerfectureMajor` in the same database query.

---

> **Note**: In 2008, [Phil Haack discovered a way to obtain data from the outer JSON array](https://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/).
> While most browser have implemented countermeasures, it is still better to use a
> JSON object as "envelope" of the data. That is why a
> [**`JsonResponse`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)
> by default does not allow something else than a `dict` as outer object. It might
> thus better to use a dictionary and keep `safe=True` on `True`.

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer, however I still have the same issue with a different error. I will try to further check on this issue and will return asap.

Comment: @rodjames: please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67343486/67579) your qustion with the new error.

Answer (score 0):

I spent 30 min solving it and I couldn't, but I came with a different solution which works the same, here is my code:

```
class PrefectureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    text = serializers.CharField(source='prefecture_name')
    # major = PrefectureMajorSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = PrefectureMinor
        fields = ['id', 'text', 'prefecture_major_id']
    
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        data['major'] = PrefectureMajorSerializer(instance).data
        return data
```

I have used `to_representation` function to add additional data to the serializer and it woks, you can try it by yourself.